# How to find out what program is sending emails

Tags: linux, email, debian, configuration

I have linux (debian) box which is running fine. 
However I have problem I need to find out what program is sending emails when i use "mail" command. Or for that matter when a PHP script is sending emails with mail() function I need to know what program is sending those emails.

How can I find out?

Ps: To clear, I'd like to know what program is invoked when I (or a program) use the "mail" command.

There are 2-3 MTA's installed on my server but I can't find out which one is responsible for sending mail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What you're asking how to do:**
`dpkg -S /path/to/mail`

/path/to/mail/ can be found using `which mail`, provided that `mail` is in your path.

*Minor Note:*
Mail also be sent out using `sendmail` instead of `mail`.

**What you should do:**
Look at your maillog, likely `/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/mail.log` the daemon name should be there.

Comment: which mail gives me `/usr/bin/mail` and when I do `dpkg -S /usr/bin/mail`It says not found. However `/var/log/mail.log`shows the daemon as postfix so I am assuming postfix is responsible for sending out emails.

Answer (score 3):

This question is similar to 
[How to find which script on my server is sending spam emails?](https://serverfault.com/questions/483650/how-to-find-which-script-on-my-server-is-sending-spam-emails) , but since it doesn't allow answer anymore (marked as duplicated), I am answering it here to provide some insights.

#### Short answer:

Change file `/etc/php.ini` or `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini` by adding those two lines: 

`mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = /var/log/phpmail.log`

restart your `php5 or php5-fpm service and nginx/apache` service, then check `/var/log/phpmail.log` file to see what script had trigger error, and remove them!

#### Long Answer:

Here is the very specific scope (my solution doesn't solve other scenario):

I am running Ubuntu in a VPS and had `nginx, php5-fpm, and wordpress` installed, and it get hacked, and I am pretty sure it was WP get hacked and spam codes were injected.

I tried the following actions to fix; such as used [Linux malware detector](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/); reset all database connection credentials; and simply eye-browsing to remove malicious codes.

Some actions I took are:

- reset all database passwords
- login wp-admin, remove unintended admin user
- install wordfence to do defense

For source code:

- you can do a diff with official wordpress code with yours, and see what are changed
- weird folders in the WP root directory
- some files ending with *.suspected
- weird files names like `1346.php`, etc.
- grep `eval` of all your files to see anything malicious
- check any `php` files that have obfuscated code

After I done those, I also remove the execute permission of all files except directory:
`chmod -x+X -R *`
or refer here: [remove execute permissions from files without touching folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296967/how-to-recursively-remove-execute-permissions-from-files-without-touching-folder)

However, I still see many errors in my `/var/log/mail.err` and `/varlog/syslog`, because I didn't configure `sendmail` or `postfix` (you can stop such services to expose the spam error):

`postfix/sendmail[2422]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory`

However, I still don't know where are the spamming scripts are... stuck here...

After searching several hours, I found the above solution mentioned in *short answer* , config your mail settings in `php.ini` and expose the location of the scripts.

After removing those scripts, I found no more spam errors, and so far my server looks clean.

Although as many suggested, you are supposed to take such server offline and do a reimage or reset to a previous status, etc.

reference links:

[How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

https://blog.rimuhosting.com/2012/09/20/finding-spam-sending-scripts-on-your-server/

Answer (score 1):

strace will expose the behaviour of your code - whether it is executing a program or making a TCP connection to a mailserver.