# How do I find out what mail program is installed/sending emails?

Tags: linux, php, email, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to find out what emailing program (if any) is sending emails on my server. My employer has a few servers, most of which use `sendmail`, but on 2 of our servers I'm not finding an email program, but somehow email has been sent with it? I don't want to just install `sendmail` if something is already setup, I'm just unsure as to how to find out what is setup. 
The server is **Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS**, and I'm using the **PHP `mail()`** command.

The only information I can find to try answering my question is Sinan's question: [How to find out what program is sending emails](https://serverfault.com/questions/434641/how-to-find-out-what-program-is-sending-emails). I tried both the answers there and found nothing.

`which mail` does nothing, and `/var/log/mail.log` is completely empty.

I tried using `strace ./mail-testing-strace.php` to see what happened when this file was executed, but I kept getting "permission denied", just like the below:

```
execve("./mail-testing-strace.php", ["./mail-testing-strace.php"], [/* 19 vars */]) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)                     = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb77ca000
_llseek(3, 0, 0xbfa1ae34, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: Permission denied\n", 32strace: exec: Permission denied
) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb77ca000, 4096)                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

The file `mail-testing-strace.php` was very basic, just having the code:

```
<?php
$to = "chris@test.com";
$subject = "Emailing Test";
$message = "This is a test, is it working?";
mail($to,$subject,$message);
?>
```

It's possible I'm not using `strace` correctly, as this is my first time trying to use it. I tried it on a server that I know sendmail is installed on and got the same message. I also tried running `strace` as the root user, but still no success.

Comment: In short, if you also have this question then check out the answer from @user156525 and the comment from **vstm**. These helped me to figure out that I had no mailserver installed. I really liked the suggestion to search on port 25. I also tried searching under the other email ports ( [found here](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-servers.html) and [here](http://www.arclab.com/products/amlc/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html) ).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try

```
$ dpkg -S `which sendmail`
```

I believe postfix is the default MTA for Ubuntu. Its main configuration file is `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

Other commands that might help:

```
# netstat -tanpl|grep :25

# lsof -i :25
```

Comment: Thanks @user156525, I tried all three of your suggestions on my known "sendmail" server (_Server A_), as well as my unknown server (_Server B_). **Server A** liked all of your suggestions while **Server B** didn't. `$ dpkg -S \`which sendmail\`` returned an error; `netstat -tanpl|grep :25` returned `(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1002 but you should be root.)` if I take `-p` out or try as root then nothing is returned; and `lsof -i :25` returned nothing as well. Since nothing is found when searching on port 25, shall I assume nothing is installed for mail?

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention that when I search for `postfix` (using `dpkg -S`) that I get a response of `The program 'postfix' is currently not installed`.

Comment: If you are not logged in as root you probably don't have `/usr/sbin` in your `$PATH`. Could you try this: `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/sendmail` (of course if the file does not exist, then you most probably don't have any mailserver installed. And regarding strace, try `strace php mail-testing-strace.php` (the permission denied error is because the file has no execute-bit set)

Comment: @vstm `/usr/sbin/sendmail` doesn't exist, so I'm just going to assume no mailserver is installed... though this doesn't make sense that this server somehow sent an email before...? And `strace php mail-testing-strace.php` worked, thanks for the suggestion! I compared the strace results from **Server A** with **B** and **B** results say `/usr/sbin/sendmail: not found`. Thank you @user156525 & @vstm, both of your suggestions helped me in my search. I'm just going to install `sendmail` now, I'll pick this answer as it was very helpful, thank you.